My repeating event with "no end date" ends after 11 occurances
My Google calendar weekly repeating task with "no end date" ends after 11 occurrences.  The first task is May 31, 2024, and the last is August 23, 2024. I have tried deleting all occurrences of the task and creating a new one from scratch.  I have tried changing the end from "no end date" to "700 occurrences".
